# Get specific text from JSON file

Tags: php, regex, string

I am looking for this type of text in a json file:

```
{"id":"*****number*******","name":"****namehere******"}
```

For example:

```
{"id":"100007015692915","name":"Ida Ka"}
```

The JSON file is a complicated JSON file that looks like this (this is part of the JSON file):

> `updated_time":"2014-02-19T15:15:31+0000","likes":{"data":[{"id":"1487307502","name":"Svatava Dohnalov\u00e1"},{"id":"662920773","name":"Alena Al Hr\u010dkov\u00e1"},{"id":"100007015692915","name":"Ida Ka"},{"id":"100000533191263","name":"Zlati V\u00e1\u0148ov\u00e1"},{"id":"1658256962","name":"Ji\u0159\u00ed Jager"},{"id":"1054706643","name":"Pavla Bubikova Winter"}],"paging":`

How can I recover all of these names and ids from a JSON file, and put them in an array?

I am using PHP and the solution would include regex probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
"id":"(\d+)","name":"(.*?)"
```

Check the capturing groups in this **[working demo](http://regex101.com/r/bF0rA5/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [65-75] `1487307502`
2.  [85-107]    `Svatava Dohnalov\u00e1`
MATCH 2
1.  [117-126]   `662920773`
2.  [136-162]   `Alena Al Hr\u010dkov\u00e1`
MATCH 3
1.  [172-187]   `100007015692915`
2.  [197-203]   `Ida Ka`
MATCH 4
1.  [213-228]   `100000533191263`
2.  [238-265]   `Zlati V\u00e1\u0148ov\u00e1`
MATCH 5
1.  [275-285]   `1658256962`
2.  [295-315]   `Ji\u0159\u00ed Jager`
MATCH 6
1.  [325-335]   `1054706643`
2.  [345-366]   `Pavla Bubikova Winter`
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `json_decode`.

```
$json = '{"id":"100007015692915","name":"Ida Ka"}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($arr);
```

Returns:

> Array ( [id] => 100007015692915 [name] => Ida Ka )

Comment: It is part of a complicated json file. So I want to extract using regex possibly

Comment: @user3138541 Post the full file, if it's all json this would very likely still be the correct way to do it.

Comment: I have posted part of the json file in the question now. It is a complicated json file with nested structure. So I would wantn to avoid json_decode probably. Please let me know if that helps

Comment: @user3138541: If it's a nested structure, then there's more reason to avoid a regex. `json_decode()` can handle nested structures very well; the function exists for just that — i.e. to work with JSON data structure. Don't use a regex for this.

Comment: The structures you want are in an array. After you decode, you'll need to loop through the array.

Comment: Yes I want to avoid looping through an array because the array is complicated and highly variable. Is there a way to do this without having to understand the array

Comment: Like he said: the more complicated it is, the harder it will be to do with a regular expression, you should just do it with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$like_data = $data['likes']['data'];
foreach($like_data as $like) {
    echo "ID: {$like['id']} Name: {$like['name']}<br/>";
}
```